# How to bind jstl form inputs with foreach?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

I'm passing a custom object to jsp. How to bind the input tags to it, keeping in mind that this custom class has lists as fields?
JSP form:

```
<f:form method="POST" action="${url_save}" modelAttribute="sprav">
<tr>
  <c:forEach var="columnName" items="${sprav.columnName}">                                           
  <td><f:input path="${columnName}"></f:input></td>                                      
 </c:forEach>
</tr>
</f:form>
```

My custom class:

```
public class Spravochnik extends BaseEntity {

    private List<String> columnName;
    private List<List<String>> valuesInRows;
    public List<String> getColumnName() {
        return columnName;
    }
    public void setColumnName(List<String> columnName) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }
    public List<List<String>> getValuesInRows() {
        return valuesInRows;
    }
    public void setValuesInRows(List<List<String>> valuesInRows) {
        this.valuesInRows = valuesInRows;
    }



}
```

BaseEntity has id only

My controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
    public ModelAndView edit(@RequestParam("id") String id, ModelMap model) {
        Spravochnik sprav = spravochnikService.selectOne(id);

        model.addAttribute("sprav", sprav);

        return new ModelAndView("edit", model);
    }
```